# How to remove thousands separator dot from the formatted numbers

Tags: python

How can I remove the dot separator from formatted numbers? I'm getting a list from a website by using regular expression:

```
a = [10.000, 20.000, 25.000]
```

How can I change them to `a = [10000, 20000, 25000]`? (They're integers now).

Comment: a = [int(x*1000) for x in a] ?

Comment: why don't you just multiply with 1000 each ?

Comment: But in my list there are different numbers which is not fit in your suggestion. (numbers are smaller than 1000)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am assuming what you have are strings, since you got them from a website, they should be text at first

```
>>> a=["10.000","20.000","25.000"]
>>> [ i.replace(".","") for i in a ]
['10000', '20000', '25000']
```

Comment: replace method doesn't work for tuples, I guess. What do you suggest for this? Should I copy the values to a list?

Comment: it depends. Because you are iterating the tuples and replacing, it should work.

Comment: OP says they're integers not strings

Answer (score 4):

Use replace as this:

```
mystring.replace('.', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a locale defined on your machine that uses dot for the thousands separator, then you can use [locale.atoi](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.atoi):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_DK.utf8')
a=['10.000','20.000','25.000']
a=map(locale.atoi,a)
print(a)
# [10000, 20000, 25000]
```

To see what locales are installed on your machine, (at least on unix), run

```
locale -a
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I would remove the dots before turning them into numbers. Instead of doing `int(num_in_string)` do this: `int(num_in_string.replace('.', ''))`